# Existence of Unimodular Congruence Transformation for Symmetric, Integer matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, integer-lattices

Two symmetric, integer valued matrices, $K_1$ and $K_2$, are congruent if there exists a unimodular integer matrix, $X$, such that $$X^T K_1 X = K_2$$
What are the conditions on the existence of such a transformation, $X$? If it can be shown that it exists, is there a general procedure for constructing such a matrix?

This can be rephrased as asking whether two integer lattices are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to see if the two integer lattices are equivalent if you have basis matrices $B_1$ and $B_2$ for them. In the op notation this would mean writing $K_1=B_1^T B_1$ and $K_2=B_2^T B_2$. If you have $B_1$ and $B_2$ you can bring them to [Hermite Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form) (HNF) (easy to do for example in Mathematica) and if the resulting form is the same for both, then they describe the same lattice in a different basis.

Comment: How would I find the basis matrices if I don't have them? Say for example that

$$K = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Alternatively, if $K_1$ and $K_2$ have the same Smith Normal Form, is it possible to show that such an $X$ must exist?

Comment: @Aegon I am not reall sure but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Similarity seems to imply you should be looking at SNF(xI-K) and not SNF(K).

Comment: That will show similarity but not conjugacy, which is what I'm trying to do. Similarity is too restrictive a condition

Comment: This is quite subtle but I am not sure that checking whether their HNF's are equal is equivalent to the criterion in the question. For instance, if $H_2=CH_1$ for some rotation $C\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$, then the criterion is fulfilled (by $C^TC=1$) but $H_2$ need not be a HNF.